# What should JAWS screen reader do when you hit space when focused on a link?

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

If you're focused on a normal link (eg not one with `role="button"`) with JAWS and you hit <kbd>space</kbd>, what should the behavior be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [keystokes guide for JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Content/Documents/Manuals/JAWS/Keystrokes.pdf) does not list any behaviour for pressing the spacebar by itself.

The behaviour will, therefore, be determined by the browser (and so it will depend on which browser you use JAWS with).

Answer (score 2):

If the focus is on a clickable element like button or link, space has usually the same effect as enter or a click: it activates the element.

Many screen reader users don't make a real difference between buttons and links: they are activable elements, that's all.

Nothing is officially specified, but that's the behavior in almost all applications and all browsers that are accessible to Jaws.